# Find multiple files' paths with the same file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tried to write a batch script that find all the paths of files that have the same name as the input string. right now it can find only the first file found, and i cant think of a way to make it list multiple files locations. I am not very experienced and I need some help.

this is part of the script code:

```
:start
    cls
    echo Enter file name with extension:
    set /p filename=
    echo Searching...

for %%a in (C D E F G H U W) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%"') do (
        set file=%%~nxb
        set folderpath=%%~dpb\
        ::the path of the file without the filename included "C:\folder\folder\"
        set fullpath=%%b
        ::the path of the file with the filename included "C:\folder\folder\file"
        goto break
  )
)
:notfound
    cls
    echo Enter file name with extension:
    echo %filename%
    echo File Not Found!
    ping localhost -n 4 >nul
    goto start

:break
    if "%folderpath:~-1%"=="\" set folderpath=%folderpath:~,-1%
    cls
    echo ? %filename% found
    echo %fullpath1%
    echo %fullpath2%
    echo %fullpath3%
    --- || ---
```

I want the script to search the computer and list every encountered files with the same name and I want to be able to put those files' paths into different variables.
For example, if readme.txt is the input, then I want the list of all the paths of all the files with that specific name (readme.txt) and I want to set variable for each path so I can use it after that.

example:

```
input:  
readme.txt

output:  
3 files found  
C:\folder\folder\readme.txt  
C:\folder\folder\folder\readme.txt  
D:\folder\readme.txt

variables:
path1 = C:\folder\folder\readme.txt
path2 = C:\folder\folder\folder\readme.txt
path3 = D:\folder\readme.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a single script which will performs the task requested. It searches all drives for your input filename with extension, puts each found full file path into a variable, then output those variables for you. I will not be tailoring the script for any new changes after this response, advising on how to integrate it into the rest of your script or supporting any changes you may subsequently make.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "SearchTerm=Enter file name with extension: "
Set "i=0"
For /F "Skip=1" %%A In ('WMIC LogicalDisk Where^
    "DriveType>1 And DriveType!=5 And FreeSpace Is Not Null" Get DeviceID'
    ) Do For %%B In (%%A) Do (For /F "Delims=" %%C In (
        'Where/F /R %%B\ "%SearchTerm%"2^>Nul') Do (Set/A i+=1
            Call Set FullPath[%%i%%]=%%C))
If %i% LSS 1 (Echo= %SearchTerm% Not Found) Else (
    Echo= %SearchTerm% had %i% match(es^)
    For /L %%A In (1,1,%i%) Do (
        Call Echo= %%%%FullPath[%%A]%%%% = %%FullPath[%%A]%%))
Timeout -1 1>Nul
```

Please be warned that searching many locations and putting many files into variables may over burden your system and cause issues.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I took your advise and instead of searching multiple files at the same time the batch file search one at the time and runs it on all of the functions, then after it search for another file and going all over again until no files left.